# Using Loops in a Python Piglatin Translator

Tags: python

I have started learning python a few hours ago on Codecademy.com and I learned how to make a Piglatin translator that would take the first letter stick it at the end and add ay after that. I create conlangs a lot and I would like to create a lexicon that I could just click on it and search for the word and it would tell me if I have that word or not. I created (well used someone elses tutorial) one that would search for the word in a notepad file and if it found one it would tell me what it is. But the problem is, it allows me to search once and then it closes. Is there a way I could make it search and then ask me if I would like to search again. I am not fluent in Python so this might sound stupid. Oh and here is my code so far

```
tDict = {} # translation dictionary

with open("Lexicon.txt", "r") as infile:    
    for line in infile:    
        s = line.split()    
        tDict[s[0]] = s[1]
wordIn = input("Enter the English word(s) to be translated: ") #raw_input() in older Python    
words = wordIn.split()    
for word in words:    
    if word in tDict.keys():    
        print(tDict[word])    
    else:    
        print("*" + word) # the word doesn't have a translation
input()
```

I put the input() at the end so that it would make me have to click enter before it would close. How could I put that into a loop that would keep asking me the same question and displaying the result until I closed the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically put the whole logic in a "while True" statement. And, if you enter "exit" like in the example below, the program will stop (with "break").

```
tDict = {}

with open("Lexicon.txt", "r") as infile:    
  for line in infile:
    s = line.split()
    tDict[s[0]] = s[1]

while True:
  wordIn = input("Enter the English word(s) to be translated (enter 'exit' to stop the program): ")

  if wordIn == "exit": break

  words = wordIn.split()
  for word in words:
    if word in tDict.keys():
      print(tDict[word])
    else:
      print("*" + word)
```

Comment: I used that code, and it gave me an error at line 4. I can't tell what the error was because it kept shutting instantly, but it looked to be with infile?

Comment: Check again please, i edited my post, it was a copy-paste error, i lost some indentation which is mandatory in Python.

Comment: Re copied it. It worked except in line 9 after (enter "exit" ...") you didn't have plus signs between the parts so it read it wrong. Fixed that, then it gave me another error saying line 3 No such file or directory. So I tried changing to Words.txt (exactly like that), that didnt't help

Comment: Try putting the fullpath to the file /path/to/lexicon.txt

Comment: So basically put C:/Conlangs/Mensprache/Lexicon/lexicon.txt?

Comment: yes, either that, or the python file must be in the same directory. Also, please check the case-sensitivity, "lexicon.txt" or "Lexicon.txt". Depending on settings, that could matter. PS: I have corrected my post, it is now 'exit' :)

Comment: I copied the newest code and it worked, although, now when I type exit, it gives me the else statement (*Exit) and doesn't actually exit. Haha

Comment: Glad to help! Sorry for the typos, writing from my tablet :)

Comment: Is it hard to create a simple GUI for it that would have an exit button and then a spot for you to type in the english word and it would display the new word for it? Sort of like Google Translate.

Comment: No, its not hard at all, unfortunately i have to run in a few minutes. But i can help you tomorrow if you are still willing and if you haven't found a solution by then.

Comment: Hi again. I can help you if you are still online. And if you haven't yet found a solution obviously :)

Comment: I am online now. I made a quick image showing basically what I had in mind. I don't have enough reputation to move to a chat, so how should we do this?

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is a `while` loop.  Look at the function `gopig` below to see how one could be used.

Note for the piglatin translator, you could do something fun like this... first using a deque, which is a doubly-linked list... then a list comprehension to process a line at a time... then you have the while loop in a function, so you can "go pig" at any time.

```
>>> def piglatinize(word):
...     from collections import deque
...     d = deque(word)
...     d.rotate(-1)
...     d.append('ay')
...     return ''.join(d)
... 
>>> def pigline(line):
...     return ' '.join(piglatinize(word) for word in line.strip().split())
... 
>>> def gopig():
...     while True:
...         line = input('Type a line to translate: ')
...         if not line: break
...         print pigline(line)
... 
>>> gopig()
Type a line to translate: "hello from a pig"
ellohay romfay aay igpay
Type a line to translate: ""
>>>
```

Then if you wanted to build up a translation dict, then replace the above function in the while loop with the one below.

```
>>> pigdict = {}
>>> def piglate(line):
...     [pigdict.update({word:piglatinize(word)}) for word in line.strip().split()]
... 
>>> piglate('hello from mars')
>>> piglate('hello from venus and earth')
>>> pigdict
{'and': 'ndaay', 'from': 'romfay', 'mars': 'arsmay', 'earth': 'artheay', 'venus': 'enusvay', 'hello': 'ellohay'}
```

Also if you are looking for an easy way to lookup whether you have the word or not, you can use `get` on the translation dict. The `*` return for the 'missing' value, as you wanted, is also used below.

```
>>> def pigfetch(word):      
...     return pigdict.get(word, '*'+word)
... 
>>> pigfetch('hello')
'ellohay'
>>> pigfetch('help')
'*help'
>>> piglate('help')
>>> pigfetch('help')
'elphay'
```

So to put it all together, you'd have this:

```
>>> def lookpig():
...     while True:
...         line = input('Type a word to find the translation: ')
...         if not line: break
...         print pigfetch(word)
...
>>> with open('words.txt', 'r') as f:
...     [piglate(line) for line in f]
...
>>> lookpig()
Type a word to find the translation: "hello"
ellohay
Type a word to find the translation: "goodbye"
*goodbye
Type a word to find the translation: ""
>>>
```

And if you already have a file-based database of words with the English word first and the Piglatin word second, you can simply do this:

```
>>> with open('lexicon.txt', 'r') as f:
...     pigdict.update(dict(line.strip().split() for line in f))
...
>>> lookpig()
Type a word to find the translation: "mars"
arsmay
Type a word to find the translation: "saturn"
*saturn
Type a word to find the translation: ""
>>>
```

Although, it might be easier to just store a python dict instead of a text file with a column of untranslated and translated words.  Or even better, use an actual database.

Comment: Thats not exactly what I was wanting. And I know an extremely easier way then that to create a piglatin translator that can translate any word without having to build a dictionary for the possible words. With just 10 lines of code and about 300 words.

Comment: Mine is 9 lines `{'piglatinize':6, 'piglate':3}`... and is **more** functional than what you were asking for.   So... you say you have a "much easier" solution that is roughly the same length?  Why don't you post it?  I'd love to see it.

Comment: The word translator `piglatinize` is only 6 lines, and doesn't require a dict.  `pigline` translates a line at a time... while `piglate` does the same but also stores to a dict.  However, to translate a word, you only need the 5 lines inside `piglatinize`.  Get it?

Comment: Nice use of a `deque` and also very nice example… however you never actually answered the OPs question.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns: Yeah... I edited to explicitly demonstrate the OPs question -- and improved the OPs code.

Comment: @WallyBeaver, basically what this one does is you type in a word and it determines what the first letter is and then moves it to the end and adds ay or whatever letters you want. I learned it from Codecademy and I am not fluent in Python yet, so I don't really understand what all yours does/doesn't, etc.

Comment: `piglatinize` first creates a `deque`, which is a special kind of list that is used to quickly transfer items from the front to the back of the list and vice versa.  Then it shifts the first letter to the end and adds `'ay'`. The last line creates a new string out of the `deque`.  So the same as what you have.  `piglate` takes a line and extracts every word in the line, then adds the word as a key in the `pigdict` and the pig latin version of the word as the value of `pigdict`.  Thus, when you call `piglate` it will add all the words you give it to a lexical dict.

Comment: `pigfetch` looks up any word in the lexical dict, and if it's there, it gets the pig latin version of the word. If not, it returns `'*'+word`, which is what your code does.  The with statement that is used to open the file is more efficient than the one you have, as it uses the filehandle's built-in iterator to pull out a line at a time from the file.   If you are trying to learn python, then play with my code above... and see what it does for yourself.

Comment: If you don't understand the code above... which is **exactly** what you want and more.  Then you might want to try it out for yourself.

Comment: Sure it does Piglatin, but that is not what I want. Read what I put and you will see. I see now that I messed up and put piglatin translator in the question title.

Comment: I added an edit to demonstrate very explicitly a translation of your code above into something functional. See the last block of code I just added. Does that make sense to you?